# EUnit vs. Common Test

Tags: erlang

I am new to Erlang.  It has 2 test frameworks: EUnit and Common Test. I am confused when to use one over another.  Can someone explain to me what are the advantages of EUnit over Common Test, and vice versa.  Seem Common Test can do everything EUnit can do and much more, not sure what I should use EUnit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

[Learn you some erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/) (one of the best online resources for erlang, besides the official doc) explains both methods quite well:

- [EUnit](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/eunit#the-need-for-tests)
- [Common Test](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/common-test-for-uncommon-tests#what-is-common-test)

As Pascal pointed out, EUnit is best used in white-box testing, more like internal function-by-function unit testing, light integration tests.

Common Test does the more heavy lifting: integration & system testing, black-box kind of stuff. It's also more complex, of course, and much more powerful.

While you're at it, you might try Dialyzer, another integrated testing tool in Erlang/OTP , which is great in locating dead or unreachable code, logical & type errors (it's a static type analyser). Again, *learn you some erlang* provides a nice introduction to it: [Dialyzer](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/types-or-lack-thereof).

Oh, by the way, if you chose to put the EUnit tests in separate files (which is perfectly possible), you won't be able to test unexported functions (that's expected). What's also expected is that Common Test does not test unexported functions: otherwise it wouldn't be a black-box testing tool (maybe a cheating one).

Comment: you can export all functions in test context, however it is even more important to make the distinction in black box tests (no export_all allowed) and white box tests (do what you want). see edit.

Comment: I confirm that the site Learn you some erlang is one of the best for erlang.

Answer (score 7):

Eunit is really simple and fit very well for module test or library test at white box level. It is integrated to rebar.

Common Test is more oriented for black box testing and application and system of application test. It comes with test coverage very easily.

**Edit** (after Andy comment):

It is right that you can use Common test for unitary white box test, as well as it is right that you can leverage eunit to some application test using fixtures.

However eUnit is very handy for simple unitary test: you write a function myFun, you add a test function myFun_test or a test generator myFun_test_ (useful to test many patterns even is some test fails in the middle) in your test module and that's it. You can run it as often as you want (no history of test).

Common test asks you to list each test case in the all function or in a group. As far as I know it has not test generator so it is less easy to go through all test patterns of each function. It is why I think it is less adapted to unitary white box tests. On the other hand, the init_per_testcase, init_per_group ... are much more flexible than eunit fixtures to organize the tests when they need some application context to run. Common Test also keeps an history of all tests done in the log directory, It is nice, but I suggest to limit the number of run to keep it useful.

**EDIT:**

To avoid the problem of not exported functions, for both eunit and common test, it is possible to use defines. for example in rebar.config (because I use separate files for eunit tests):

```
{eunit_compile_opts, [{d,'EUNIT_TEST',true}]}.
{erl_opts, [debug_info, warn_export_all]}.
```

and in a module, if it is necessary:

```
%% export all functions when used in eunit context
-ifdef(EUNIT_TEST).
-compile(export_all).
-endif.
```

You can verify that it only modify the compiled code for eunit

```
D:\git\helper>rebar clean eunit compile
==> helper (clean)
==> helper (eunit)
Compiled test/help_list_tests.erl
Compiled test/help_ets_tests.erl
Compiled test/help_num_tests.erl
Compiled src/help_ets.erl
Compiled src/help_list.erl
Compiled src/helper.erl
src/help_num.erl:6: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
Compiled src/help_num.erl
Compiled src/help_code.erl
  All 31 tests passed.
Cover analysis: d:/git/helper/.eunit/index.html
==> helper (compile)
Compiled src/help_ets.erl
Compiled src/help_list.erl
Compiled src/helper.erl
Compiled src/help_num.erl
Compiled src/help_code.erl
```

Comment: thanks Pascal.  I talked with some Erlang engineers, the only reason I got is common_test cannot test unexported functions.

Comment: This isn't true, you embed tests in the source module so you can test whatever you want.

Comment: I have edited my answer following Andy comment. I am not aware of this way to use common test, I write the test cases in test_SUITE.erl modules

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/basics_chapter.html:

Common Test is also a very useful tool for white-box testing Erlang code (e.g. module testing), since the test programs can call exported Erlang functions directly and there's very little overhead required for implementing basic test suites and executing simple tests. For black-box testing Erlang software, Erlang RPC as well as standard O&M interfaces can for example be used.